# split String bye last found char

Tags: java

How to split some String by last found char in java?

```
"(abcab, a)" should result {"abc","b"}
"(aklbamabcabdef, a)" should result {"aklbamabc","bdef"}
```

Comment: The last founded char?

Comment: What is "last found char"?

Comment: How this question got a upvote?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post what you have tried? ... Or are you just asking the good people of SO to work out something that you haven't put any effort into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homework?

```
    String string="adacda";
    char toFind='d';
    String result=string.substring(string.lastIndexOf(toFind));
    System.out.println(result);
```

If you want to achieve that using a regular expression, use

```
    /.*d([^d]*)/
```

to get everything past the last 'd' character for example  in the first capturing group

http://regex101.com/r/vP3kT8/1

Comment: no but I thought there could be elegant way to achieve that with RegEx

Comment: Well, i'm not sure whether it's more elegant or efficient... but I'm adding an regex solution

Answer (score 0):

Given the split character is `'a'`, you could do the following:

```
String test = "abcab";
int idx = test.lastIndexOf('a');
return new String[] {test.substring(0x00,idx),test.substring(idx+0x01)};
```

Or see the [jdoodle demo](http://jdoodle.com/a/88).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. You are looking at `lastIndexOf()`

```
    String str="(abcab, a)";
    int lastIndex=str.lastIndexOf('a');
    System.out.println(str.substring(1,lastIndex));
    System.out.println(str.substring(lastIndex,str.length()-1));
```